# CGImageRef not releasing

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, cgimageref

I encountered a problem when using СП

```
for (int16_t j = 0; j <= 1/kAlphaStep; j++) {
            UIImage *blendingImage = [UIImage imageByBlendingImage:firstImage andImage:secondImage alpha:kAlphaStep*j];
            buffer = [self pixelBufferFromImage:blendingImage andSize:size];
...}
```

And

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBufferFromImage:(UIImage *)img andSize:(CGSize)size {
CGImageRef image = img.CGImage;
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                         nil];
CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;

CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, size.width,
                                      size.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,
                                      &pxbuffer);
NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);
...
return pxbuffer;
```

}

And while I'm in the loop, all `CGImageRef` in memory.

If I use

```
if (image) {
    CGImageRelease(image);
}
```

app crashed. 
Please help me!!

Comment: Your's image is owned by pxbuffer. You need release pxbuffer instead.

Comment: You should rename your's `pixelBufferFromImage` to `createPixelBufferFromImage` to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: @Cy-4AH `pxbuffer` is releasing in first loop 
`if(buffer) 
{
                        CVBufferRelease(buffer);
                        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];
                    }`
Problem exactly in CGImageRef.
If i'm releasing **image** in loop - it's not memory warning, but crashed after `viewDidApear`. If i'm not releasing **image** it's not crashed, but have many memory warnings

Comment: You cannot do all that image processing in a loop. Instead, do the process one at a time in a timer callback. That way, only 1 processing steps is done every N ms. The way you wrote the code will just crash your device, so you need to start over with a step by step approach spread out over time.